# binding Maybe value in do-block works while it does not work in a function

Tags: haskell

In the following example, "try 0" works and I get "Nothing" while "try2 0" does not work and I get "Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern Just (x, y)"
I don't know how I get "Nothing" from "try 0" ... because the output of "calc n" is binded to (x,y)...Please help me understand why..

```
try n = do
  (x,y) <- calc n
  return (x+1, y+1)

try2 n = (x+1,y+1)
  where
    Just (x,y) = calc n

calc x
  | x == 0 = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just (x+1, 1)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ try 0
```

Comment: `try` desugars to: `try n = calc n >>= \(x, y) -> return (x+1, y+1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get `Nothing` from `try` because you get `Nothing` from `calc`. The `Maybe` Monad instance (which you invoke via `do`-notation) propagates the `Nothing` forward to the output. `try2` fails because you attempt to match `Nothing` with the pattern `Just (x,y)`. These obviously don't match because one is a `Just` and one is a `Nothing`.